# Full instruction for download OSM data in Ubuntu 12.04 LTC

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openstreetmap, postgresql, mapproxy

Is there instruction for:

1) install software

2) download OSM data in Postgis database

3) set styles

4) generate tiles

5) initilaze MapProxy   (all in OS Linux)

6) View map (generated tiles) in ArcGis Server (or Geoserver) (in OS Windows)

Comment: You can start with [this reference](http://blog.burhum.com/post/49974918193/ubuntugis-gis-on-linux) on installing PostGIS and follow up with [osm2pgsql](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql) which should get you through step 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is solved. All steps you can find in:

http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-12-04/